# positioning flot xaxis labels

Tags: javascript, axis, flot

I am making a plot using flot that has tickmarks at irregular positions,  e.g. one at position 100,  one at position 155,  one at position 230.  Flot is able to put the tickmarks at those locations easily enough.

But I want to put axis labels in between these points,  e.g.

```
|--------------|-------|------------------|
    blahblah       huh        metoo
```

Can't figure out how to get flot to  this.   Any sugestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses the multiple axis capabilities of flot to add a second axis with your labels:

[image]

Code:

```
       $.plot($("#placeholder"),
       [ { data: [[1,1],[12,12],[45,45],[2,2],[7,7],[90,90],[112,112],[145,145],[87,87],[250,250]]},
         { data: [[]], xaxis: 2}], //second empty series
           {
               xaxes: [ {ticks:[100,155,230]}, // force tick location
                        {ticks: [50,127.5,192.5], // label locations, center them based on forced tick locations
                         min: 0, max: 250, // set min and max to scale 2nd axis
                         tickFormatter: // return string label instead of number
                           function formatter(val, axis) { 
                             if (val == 50) return "blahblah";
                             else if (val == 127.5) return "huh";
                             else if (val == 192.5) return "metoo";
                             else return "";
                          }} ]
           });​
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QJF7x/).